# Selenium Unable to Get Link of Image inside iframe > iframe > img

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, selenium-rc, domxpath

I am facing an issue in getting element using selenium python.
Element wrap inside two iframes tags. Hierarchy given below

```
iframe > iframe > a
```

xpath manually working fine. But using selenium it giving me error given below

```
//img[contains(@href,'google')]
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'switch' into the iframe, Selenium has the built-in [`switch_to`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=switch_to#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) method for this.

Example: `driver.switch_to.frame('frame_name')`

You can read the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html?#moving-between-windows-and-frames) for more help and examples.

Comment: Hey Tortoise. I did same as you mentioned. But it can't able to detect google ads url its work with other iframes. It causes problem only with google ads iframe.